# Es6 merge two objects using spread not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to merge two javascript objects using spread operators , 
but i am unable to produce the expected result.
Here is my first objects list ( objects wrapped inside object)

```
var arr2 = {
  "20080": {
    "ProductQuantitesId": 20080,    
    "CustomerPrice": 100,
    "DisplayQuantity": "20 L",   
    "DisplayProductName": "Bisleri Mineral Water",
    "DiscountedPrice": 20,
    "DiscountedPercentage": 17
  },
  "20110": {
    "ProductQuantitesId": 20110,   
    "CustomerPrice": 270,
    "DisplayQuantity": "5 kgs",    
    "DisplayProductName": "Srujana Curd Bucket",
    "DiscountedPrice": 30,
    "DiscountedPercentage": 10
  } }
```

Second object list is

```
var arr3 = {
  "20080": {
    "Qty": 2,


  },
  "20110": {
    "Qty": 3,
  } }
```

I want to merge this 2 objects using es6 spread.

```
const result = {...arr2,...arr3}
```

Expecting Qty to be added to the objects , but i am seeing only Qty.
Result i am getting

```
{
  "20080": {
    "Qty": 2
  },
  "20110": {
    "Qty": 3
  }
}
```

Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr3` is overwriting the values from `arr2` because both objects share the same keys. Assuming `arr2` and `arr3`'s keys are identical, you can use the following solution:

---

```js
var arr2 = {
  "20080": {
    "ProductQuantitesId": 20080,    
    "CustomerPrice": 100,
    "DisplayQuantity": "20 L",   
    "DisplayProductName": "Bisleri Mineral Water",
    "DiscountedPrice": 20,
    "DiscountedPercentage": 17
  },
  "20110": {
    "ProductQuantitesId": 20110,   
    "CustomerPrice": 270,
    "DisplayQuantity": "5 kgs",    
    "DisplayProductName": "Srujana Curd Bucket",
    "DiscountedPrice": 30,
    "DiscountedPercentage": 10
  } 
}

var arr3 = {
  "20080": {
    "Qty": 2,
  },
  "20110": {
    "Qty": 3,
  } 
}

// First, get the keys from arr2 using Object.keys().
// Then, use Array.prototype.reduce() to iterate through the keys.
// In the callback, acc is referring to the empty object, {}, 
// passed as the second argument in reduce().
const result = Object.keys(arr2).reduce((acc, key) => {

    // Set the value of the resulting object's key equal to the 
    // combined key-values of arr2 and arr3
    acc[key] = { ...arr2[key], ...arr3[key] }
    
    // Make sure to return the object
    return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Spread properties in object initializers copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto the newly created object.

So this code will work:

```js
var arr2 = {
  "20080": {
    "ProductQuantitesId": 20080,    
    "CustomerPrice": 100,
    "DisplayQuantity": "20 L",   
    "DisplayProductName": "Bisleri Mineral Water",
    "DiscountedPrice": 20,
    "DiscountedPercentage": 17
  },
  "20110": {
    "ProductQuantitesId": 20110,   
    "CustomerPrice": 270,
    "DisplayQuantity": "5 kgs",    
    "DisplayProductName": "Srujana Curd Bucket",
    "DiscountedPrice": 30,
    "DiscountedPercentage": 10
  } }
  
  var arr3 = {
  "20080": {
    "Qty": 2,


  },
  "20110": {
    "Qty": 3,
  } }
  
  for (let property in arr2) {
    if (arr2.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
       arr2[property] = {...arr2[property], ...arr3[property]};
    }
  }
  
  console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have same keys then it will always be overwritten by the last one

```js
let first = { a: 'first' }
let second = { a : 'second' }

let firstAtEnd = {...second, ...first}

console.log(firstAtEnd)

let secondAtEnd = {...first, ...second}

console.log(secondAtEnd)
```

To achieve what you're trying to you can loop through keys of of one of them and merge with the value of other one

```js
var arr2 = {"20080": {"ProductQuantitesId": 20080,"CustomerPrice": 100,"DisplayQuantity": "20 L","DisplayProductName": "Bisleri Mineral Water","DiscountedPrice": 20,"DiscountedPercentage": 17},"20110": {"ProductQuantitesId": 20110,"CustomerPrice": 270,"DisplayQuantity": "5 kgs","DisplayProductName": "Srujana Curd Bucket","DiscountedPrice": 30,"DiscountedPercentage": 10}}

var arr3 = {"20080": {"Qty": 2,},"20110": {"Qty": 3,}}

let newObj = {}
for (let property in arr2) {
  if (property in arr3) {
    newObj[property] = { ...arr2[property],
      ...arr3[property]
    };
  }
}

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. it helped a lot to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

With the way you have used the spread operator, it finds that the second object has the same key as the first one so it replaces the first one's property with the second object's property.

I think what you have to do in this case is to iterate through the keys of the first object and merge one key at a time to a new object. like below.

```js
var arr2 = {
  "20080": {
    "ProductQuantitesId": 20080,    
    "CustomerPrice": 100,
    "DisplayQuantity": "20 L",   
    "DisplayProductName": "Bisleri Mineral Water",
    "DiscountedPrice": 20,
    "DiscountedPercentage": 17
  },
  "20110": {
    "ProductQuantitesId": 20110,   
    "CustomerPrice": 270,
    "DisplayQuantity": "5 kgs",    
    "DisplayProductName": "Srujana Curd Bucket",
    "DiscountedPrice": 30,
    "DiscountedPercentage": 10
  } }

var arr3 = {
  "20080": {
    "Qty": 2,


  },
  "20110": {
    "Qty": 3,
  } }


const result = {}
for (let key of Object.keys(arr2)) {
 result[key] = { ...arr2[key], ...arr3[key] }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries` and `map` to achieve this

```js
var arr2 = {"20080": {"ProductQuantitesId": 20080,"CustomerPrice": 100,"DisplayQuantity": "20 L","DisplayProductName": "Bisleri Mineral Water","DiscountedPrice": 20,"DiscountedPercentage": 17},"20110": {"ProductQuantitesId": 20110,"CustomerPrice": 270,"DisplayQuantity": "5 kgs","DisplayProductName": "Srujana Curd Bucket","DiscountedPrice": 30,"DiscountedPercentage": 10}}

var arr3 = {"20080": {"Qty": 2,},"20110": {"Qty": 3,}}

var res = Object.entries(arr2)
                .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: {...v, ...(arr3[k] || {})} }))
                .reduce((a, b) => ({...a, ...b}))

console.log(res)
```